# Property Count of collection not initialized

Tags: javascript, web-part, jsom

I get an error, when I try to get all web parts of a page.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

//get all webparts for current site
var page = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
var limitedWebPartManager = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webParts = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

ctx.load(webParts, 'Include(WebPart.Properties, Id)');

ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < webParts.get_count(); i++) {
        // Do something
    }
}), function (e, a) {
    utility.log(a);
});
```

The error happens when calling webParts.get_count()

The error-message is:

> the collection has not been initialized

The same error occurs when I use the enumerator of the collection.

But when I look into the object with the inspector, I can find the retrieved data of all webparts.

Some more information: The page is in a publishing page and the error occurs when I open the edit mode.

Has someone an idea how to solve it?

To iterate through the internal array does not look very nice ;)

Comment: Can you try this: `ctx.load(webParts,'Include(WebPart)');`

Comment: I can't reproduce it - does this happen always for you? Is there a way for me to reproduce it?

Comment: It happens when I have a published page and I open the edit-mode. But not only random :/

Comment: Sorry, I mean it happens randomly

Comment: @NadeemYousuf Sorry, but it does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a workarround. It seems that SharePoint is not able to parse the response from the server sometimes.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

//get all webparts for current site
var page = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
var limitedWebPartManager = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var webParts = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

ctx.load(webParts, 'Include(WebPart.Properties, Id)');

ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
    // Workarround when not correctly parsed
    webParts = webParts.$12_1 ? webParts : webParts.$5_0.$1t_0;

    for (var i = 0; i < webParts.get_count(); i++) {
        // Do something
    }
}), function (e, a) {
    utility.log(a);
});
```

In the object webParts.$5_0.$1t_0 is the correct SP.WebPartDefinitionCollection object.